# Manipulating string line by line using javascript

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a text area with some sentences like below

Whats up

How you doing

Thats all

I`ll have to convert the uppercase letters into lowercase and vice verse, the output should be like below

wHATS UP

hOW YOU DOING

tHATS ALL

Now, how can I manipulate the sentences line by line using Javascript ?

Comment: I took the value of textarea to a string variable and converted the letter cases. But when I`m putting that changed string to the textarea that is not coming as separated by lines.

Comment: you need to provide a minimal, complete and verifiable question. SO isn't a code writing service. you need to show us your code

Comment: Okay I`ll. Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
var lines = $('textarea').val().split('\n');

for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
 }
```

Comment: code only answers aren't useful for the community. Plaese look at [answer]

Answer (score 0):

lets see an example with the first string

```
function invertCase (str) {
 for (var i=0; i< str.length; i++) {
   if(str.charAt(i).toUpperCase()===str.charAt(i)){
     str = str.split('').splice(i,1,str.charAt(i).toLowerCase()).join();
   } else {
     str =str.split('').splice(i,1,str.charAt(i).toUpperCase()).join();
   }
return str;
}
```